# `kubectl patch` each element of array

Tags: kubectl, json-patch

I would like to patch *all* container templates in a Kubernetes deployment with a single `kubectl patch` command, without having to know their name. Is that possible?

I know I am able to achieve the replacement through `awk`, `sed`, `jq` and `kubectl replace`, but I would favour something like a `[*]` in the expression...

**Patch command for a certain container spec**

```
kubectl patch deployment mydeployment -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"myname","imagePullPolicy":"Always"}]}}}}'
```

**Example Deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: example.com/my/fancyimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: myname
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: I am absolutely certain that I will be able to find the answer through the [Kubectl patch.go source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/patch.go), [evanphx/json-patch library](https://github.com/evanphx/json-patch), [RFC 6902](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) and [RFC 7396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396). That will take quite some time that I am not able to invest for that script. Maybe we are able to be good craftsman and find a neat solution here...

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked, since i use here command line tools, but if it would appear here, it would save me some time. So i post it for others, who come here from search engines.

```
kubectl \
  --username=USERNAME \
  --password=PASSWORD \
  --server="https://EXAMPLE.COM" \
  --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true \
  --namespace=MY_NAMESPACE \
  get deployments | \
  grep -v NAME | cut -f1 -d" " | \
  xargs kubectl \
    --username=USERNAME \
    --password=PASSWORD \
    --server="https://EXAMPLE.COM" \
    --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true \
    --namespace=MY_NAMESPACE \
    patch deployment \
      -p='{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"myname","imagePullPolicy":"Always"}]}}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice way of achieving this, assuming you want this to be an ongoing requirement, would be to use the [AlwaysPullImages AdmissionController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#alwayspullimages)

> **AlwaysPullImages**
>
> This admission controller modifies every new Pod to force the image pull policy to Always...

You would apply this to your api controller by appending it to the `--enable-admission-plugins` argument